# Why Laravel skip the second Foreach()

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

i have a simple function but when i am debugging i found out that the second Foreach() get skipped avery time:

this is my code:

```
foreach ($request->option as $option){
        $option = $product->option()->create([
            'name'=>$option['name'],
        ]);
        foreach($option['variant'] as $variant) {
            dd('variantSection');
            $option->variant()->create([
                'name'=>$variant
            ]);
        }
    }
    dd('great');
```

In this case i think it should print "variantSection" but instead i get "great".

Comment: You are overriding the $option variable. Try using different names for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure since no sample data was provided, but you are overriding the `$option` variable. Try renaming it:

```
foreach ($request->option as $requestOption){
        $option = $product->option()->create([
            'name'=>$requestOption['name'],
        ]);
        foreach($requestOption['variant'] as $variant) {
            dd('variantSection');
            $option->variant()->create([
                'name'=>$variant
            ]);
        }
    }
    dd('great');
```